# pow operation wih long numbers in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I am trying to make the operation pow(49999994,13) which results 1.220701e+100. But when i do in objective c i got the result -9223372036854775808. How can I do this operation in Objective-C correctly?

Comment: `printf("Pow: %g\n", pow(49999994,13));` works just fine for me. What type are you storing your result into, and how do you inspect its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no pow operator in Objective-C, so use C or NSDecimalNumber (preferred).

#### pow

```
NSLog(@"%f",(double)pow(49999994,13));        // OK 12207012207044960421719...
NSLog(@"%f",(long long int)pow(49999994,13)); // WRONG -9223372036854775808
```

`-92233...` results from using a `long long int` instead a `double`.

#### NSDecimalNumber

As noted by Martin R, the proper way to do it in Objective-C is `NSDecimalNumber`, which produces as many accurate digits as possible followed by zeros.

```
    NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"49999994e0"];
    n = [n decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:13];
    NSLog(@"nsdecimal %@",n);
```

Compare the results:

```
 accurate 12207012207044960931467189309843359073812548192494216675520514965298161665721254575494908505339305984
nsdecimal 12207012207044960931467189309843359073800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      pow 12207012207044960421719677106210881027530912788496417091073101786581413645039745611250537465292783616.000000
```

Comment: *"There is no pow operator in Objective-C"* - In some sense, there is:  `decimalNumberByRaisingToPower`.

Comment: Thank you.Now i am getting the correct number from pow operation. And now i want to get the module of the result number with the number 99999989 with fmod(number,99999989) but i am gettin wrong result from this operation too. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Check if you are not doing like this : double result=pow(49999994,13);
    NSLog(@"%f",result);
    
    double mod=fmod(result, 100000);
    NSLog(@"%f",mod);

Comment: @user1765253: `49999994 ^ 13` is a number with 101 digits. A `double` can store only about 37 significant digits, so you loose precision, therefore `fmod(number,99999989)` *cannot* be correct. To compute `(49999994 ^ 13) mod 99999989` precisely, you either have to use some "big number" library, or use a [Modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the method declaration of pow() it is something like this :

```
double pow(double, double);
```

And you saved the result into `long int` or you printed using integer(s) specifiers, resulting in exceeding the max limit of `long int`.

You can use it as :

```
 double result=pow(49999994,13);
```